# How to set custom resolution for screen recording using media recorder in android programmatically?

Tags: android, screen-resolution, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, screen-recording

I am actually implementing screen recording in android devices. I want my videos to be recorded in custom resolution before recording like 360p , 480p , 720p.
I've tried to set height and width in mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(width*height) but it only changes the size of screen recording .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `CamcorderProfile` and `hasProfile()` to see what profiles are supported on the device, and choose from those.

See the documentation here for the list of defined resolutions:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile

Here is another guide which may help as well:

https://medium.com/jamesob-com/recording-your-android-screen-7e0e75aae260